# How can I remember a parameter from the previous page so I can go back to it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I was thinking how to go back from an individual listing page to the index page (with the previous page). It's pretty much like "go back" function. But I don't want to always go to the 1st page.

The indexed page has parameter of page.
localhost:3000/listings?page=2

But inside each listing, the URL lacks the page number information. 
localhost:3000/listings/1

I was using rails 4.1.8 and Kaminari 0.16.3

List controller

```
  def index
    @listings = Listing.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page])
  end
```

Index page:

```
<%= paginate @listings %>
```

Show page partial:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', root_path %>
```

routes:

```
root 'listings#index'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by storing values in the session

```
def index
  if params[:page]
    session[:listing_index_page] = params[:page]
  end
  @listings = Listing.order("created_at DESC").page(session[:listing_index_page])
end
```

If the user navigates to `listings/index` for the first time, there will be no page param and Kaminari should assume page 1. Subsequently navigating to page 2 will store 2 in the session.

If the user returns to the index page later (without an explicit page param) the value will be retrieved from the session.